# Знак за несуществующую метку?

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки

При просмотре значка [*Систематизатор*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), видно человека, который получил этот знак за создание метки [decode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decode).

> [image: скриншот]

Однако, если перейти по метке, видно, что метка еще не была задокументирована. Это какая-то ошибка, или почему так происходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В знаке чётко написано:

> Создать метку, используемую в 50 вопросах.

Вопросов сейчас 52, так что требование выполняется.

---

А за описание даются отдельные знаки:

- [Редактор меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor)

  > Первая правка описания метки.
- [Научный ассистент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant)

  > Отредактировать описание 50 меток.

Comment: Я все равно что-то не до конца понимаю, а какое отношение человек на скрине, имеет отношение к этой метке?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive, _"**Создать метку**, используемую в 50 вопросах."_ - ну написано же. Он её создал.

Comment: а почему тогда нет никакой документации, и истории о ее создании?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive, создатель показывается только у новых меток. Что-то намутили...